Can I use ChainLink and Oracles to secure an unsupervised business operation?
For example, could a potential manufacturing and distribution partner in Brazil be monitored, and audited to have actions triggered like distribution of sales revenue based on receipt of sales revenue?
Trust is high, I am just wondering what is the potential to create trustable semi-off-hands businesses with global partners.
Al
